# "database locked" error in ios while updating query

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am using the below code **to update the query** using `sqlite`.
But am getting `"database is locked error"`.
I tried searching some SO link and it was suggested to close database, but I did that again am getting the same error. I have mentioned where I am getting error in the code.

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *locationNo =NULL;
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count(*) from code"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            locationNo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            int count= [locationNo intValue];
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSLog(@"%@",locationNo);
            if(0==count)
            {
                NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into favourite_code (code_id,code_1,code_2,code_3,code_4,code_5,code_6, status, record_status) VALUES (\"%d\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",1 ,code1,code2,code3,code4,code5,code6,@"Y", @"Y"];

                const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
                sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    return YES;
                }
                else {
                    return NO;
                }
                sqlite3_reset(statement);
                sqlite3_close(database);
            }
            else{


                =========================== Getting Error in the below lines =========================

                const char *sq1l = "update code SET code_1=?, code_2=?, code_3=?, code_4=?, code_5=?,code_6=? WHERE code_id=1";

                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sq1l, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [code1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                }

                int success = sqlite3_step(statement);
                if (success != SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    //result = FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    //result = TRUE;
                }

                =================================END=========================================   


            }

            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Not found");
            locationNo=@"1";
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally you will get this if you have multiple queries going on at the same time (either you didn't finalize some early SQL statement, or you have multiple threads open, or you've opened the database multiple times).

This code has a slightly confusing use of `sqlite3_close` and `sqlite3_reset` (and a lack of `sqlite3_finalize`), which might be the source of the problem.

In [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://sqlite.org/cintro.html), they point out the correct order of the statements:

- `sqlite3_open()`, to open a database
- `sqlite3_prepare()`, to prepare a sql statement
- `sqlite3_bind()`, to bind values to ? placeholders as necessary
- `sqlite3_step()`, to execute the sql and/or step through the results
- `sqlite3_column()`, to retrieve the columns of data, as necessary
- `sqlite3_finalize()`, to complete/close the prepared sql statement
- `sqlite3_close()`, to close the database

Bottom line, your [`sqlite3_open`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) call is not matched with a single [`sqlite3_close`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) statement at the end (but you have an extraneous `sqlite3_close` in the middle of your code). Also, each [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) must have its own [`sqlite3_finalize`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) (you only use [`sqlite3_reset`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) if you want to reset a prepared statement so you can bind it with new values and step through it again; but you still need `sqlite3_finalize` when you're all done with the prepared statement).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried wht you have said. I removed sql_close and did only finalize I removed reset also still am getting the same error. Am I doing it correct? Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @2vision2 The closing the database and replacing the reset with finalize are necessary steps. But the root problem is probably that you're opening the database twice. For example, your code snippet opens the database at the start, but doesn't close it at the end. If you ran this twice, you'd have problems. Make sure you match up your open and close statements. It's very important to make sure every `sqlite3_open` has a `sqlite3_close` and that every `sqlite3_prepare_v2` has a `sqlite3_finalize`.

Comment: @2vision2 Also, are you doing any multi-threaded code here (e.g. GCD, `NSOperationQueue`, or any asynchronous techniques)? Special care must be taken when accessing a database from multiple threads/queues.

Comment: yes you are right! For every open I dont have a close Now it got worked after matching every open with a close. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I'd spent several hours trying to fix this. However I wasn't using finalize in a loop. Thanks.